# Вывод записей категории в шаблоне статической страницы

Tags: php, wordpress, archive

Стоит задача создать заглавную страницу для категорий материалов. То есть не просто вывести на сайт/category/раздел/подраздел цикл имеющихся записей (archive.php), а чтобы на отдельной статической странице сайт/раздел/подраздел (page.php) со своей структурой и наполнением был также встроен цикл записей нужной категории.
К примеру, на полноценной странице категории со своим заголовком и текстом "этот раздел сайта о том-то и о том, потому что то и се... и вообще еще вот тут ссылочки, фоточки и картинки... а подробней смотри здесь:" И ниже выводятся записи, относящиеся к данной категории.
Мои действия (на конкретном примере):

1. Создал шаблон страницы категории page-glagol.php:

```html
<?php get_header(); ?>

<section id="casing">
<div class="wrapper">

<!-- <middle> -->
<div id="content" class="wide-page">

<?php the_content(); ?>
    
<div class="cat-wrap">
        <?php
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'posts_per_page' => 10,
                'category_name' => get_the_content(),
            );
        $query = new WP_Query( $args );
            while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

<div class="flex-cat">
<div class="entry">
<!-- Анонс (вывод контента до more) -->
<?php the_content(); ?>

<div class="date clear"><?php the_time('d.m.Y'); ?></div>
<div class="tag">
<div>Раздел: <?php the_category(', '); ?></div>
<div>Тэги: <?php the_tags('',', ',''); ?></div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="pic-thumb"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div>
</div>

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
</div>


</div>
<!-- </middle> -->

<div class="clr"></div>

</div>
</section>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

2. Добавил в functions.php строку add_post_type_support( 'page', 'content' );

На странице https://riggo.ru/glagol/ контент отображается, а цикл под ним не сработал. Со страницы https://riggo.ru/category/glagol/ материалы выводятся (дизайн материалов еще не правил, поэтому там пока каша)

Comment: Не совсем понял, чего вы хотите добиться. Если вы хотите отдельный шаблон для страниц категорий, то в корне темы создайте файл `category.php` и наполняйте его. В таком файле доступен цикл wordpress с заранее выбранными записями.

Comment: В моей теме изначально не было category.php. ОК, попробую. Вероятно это то, что мне и нужно

Comment: И получается, что наполнение будет не через создание новой страницы, а внутри шаблона? А нет возможности вставки php-цикла, не в шаблон, а на прямо на нужную станицу?

Comment: Что значит "со своим дизайном"? Это вообще-то противопоказано практически для любого сайта, (кроме очень редких случаев). И что кроме списка постов нужно выводить на страницах рубрик? Исправь свой вопрос, дописав ответы на эти вопросы.

Comment: Делается элементарно: создаёте файл page-слаг.php (где слаг - это адрес Вашего подраздела), в коде этого файла создаёте стандартный wp loop с выводом записей из нужной категории в нужном Вам дизайне. Только имейте в виду, что `сайт/раздел/подраздел` в данном случае - это должны быть страницы, а не категории и подкатегории записей.

Comment: То есть для каждой страницы раздела надо создать свой шаблон? Универсальный шаблон, который подхватывал бы записи одноименной категории не создать?

Comment: Так универсальный шаблон работает в `сайт/category/раздел/подраздел`. А по Вашему вопросу я понял, что Вы хотите где-то на отдельной странице вывести посты определённой категории в новом дизайне. Для этого и нужен отдельный шаблон с новым дизайном.

Comment: Универсальный шаблон для страниц разделов. Чтобы можно было подставлять для каждого раздела сверху свои заголовки и "бла-бла1", "бла-бла2"... А ниже чтоб подхватывался цикл вывода записей нужной категории

Comment: Если Вы хотите универсальный шаблон для страниц разделов, тогда Вам понадобятся дополнительные поля. То есть заголовок и описание раздела у Вас будут в the_title() и the_content(), а всю дополнительную информацию ("и вообще еще вот тут ссылочки, фоточки и картинки") нужно где-то хранить. Есть хороший плагин ACF, с его помощью можно быстро и легко настроить нужные поля.

Comment: Но если разделов у Вас немного, то проще создать под каждую страницу свой page-слаг.php и там спокойно разместить весь нужный контент безо всяких дополнительных полей и т.д.

Comment: А можно подцепить к стандартной/универсальной странице (к шаблону) ссылку на отдельный cicle.php с материалами и с условием для показа определенной категории? К примеру, в шаблоне page.php после the_content() (как раз это и есть поле для вывода всех предварительных бла-бла страницы) записать какой-нибудь get_cicle(), в котором и будет прописан цикл. Мысль, что все бла-бла для каждого раздела будут висеть и редактироваться через шаблон, не очень вдохновляет

Comment: Только не ссылку на cicle.php и не в page.php (потому что это универсальный шаблон вообще для всех страниц сайта). Можно создать условный `мой_шаблон.php`, где перед `get_header()` сразу после `<?php` прописать `/* Template Name: Шаблон страницы для вывода записей */` и уже в этом шаблоне прописать универсальный wp loop, в котором имя категории будет переменной - в зависимости от того,  на какой странице мы находимся.

Comment: Ох... написано красиво. Осталось как-то реализовать

Comment: Кинул в ответ примерный вариант, как может выглядеть такой шаблон

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Код Вашего условного шаблона может быть примерно таким. Слаг категории в запрос к базе здесь передаётся через поле "отрывок", которое нужно открыть путём добавления в functions.php строки `add_post_type_support( 'page', 'excerpt' );` Наверное, можно придумать и какой-то другой способ передачи, но этот мне показался самым простым.

```html
<?php

/* Template Name: Страница для произвольного вывода записей */

get_header(); ?>

<div class="container">

    <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    <div class="page-content"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
    
    <div class="news-wrap">
        <?php
            $args = array(
                'post_type' => 'post',
                'posts_per_page' => 10,
                'category_name' => get_the_excerpt(),
            );

        $query = new WP_Query( $args );
            while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post(); ?>

        <div class="news-item">
            <h2 class="new-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><img src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" alt=""></a>
        </div>

        <?php endwhile; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
    </div>

</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Так Вы можете создавать родительские и дочерние страницы, выбирая данный шаблон из списка и прописывая в поле "отрывок" слаг нужного раздела/подраздела записей.

**ВАЖНО!** Имейте в виду, что при переходе непосредственно на саму запись url в адресной строке вернётся в каноническое состояние: `сайт/category/раздел/подраздел/запись` (и если у Вас используются "хлебные крошки", с ними произойдёт то же самое). Потому что страницы и записи - это разные сущности, и объединить их в одну древовидную структуру не получится.

Comment: У меня анонсы идут через the_conternt. Как тогда обернуть в цикл мой код: <div class="flex-cat">
<div class="entry">
<?php the_content(); ?>
<div class="date clear"><?php the_time('d.m.Y'); ?></div>
<div class="tag">
<div>Раздел: <?php the_category(', '); ?></div>
<div>Тэги: <?php the_tags('',', ',''); ?></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="pic-thumb"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div>
</div>

Comment: @Baddy, не очень понял. the_content() в моём коде выводит статический контент статической страницы. Причём тут цикл?

Comment: у меня анонсы выведены через content, а не excerpt

Comment: @Baddy, так это анонсы записей же, а не страницы? Ну и выводите их в цикле, там же, где у меня выведены заголовок и картинка. Только странное это у Вас решение - the_content() выводит полное содержимое записи

Comment: анонсы оборваны через <more>

Comment: @Baddy, тогда всё должно получиться )

Comment: Попробовал и ваш вариант, и через get_posts. Вывод цикла не срабатывает. Знаний и ума не хватает понят, в чем загвоздка. Исправлю топик, выложу там код

Comment: @Baddy, Ваша ошибка в том, что Вы создаёте страницу с тем же слагом, что и у раздела - потому и не работает. Слаг у страницы должен быть другой и шаблон должен называться как-то иначе, типа my_temp.php (а не page-glagol.php), чтобы никакие страницы его случайно не приняли за свой.

Comment: @Baddy, в шаблоне надо обязательно прописать какой-нибудь Template Name типа `/* Template Name: Страница для произвольного вывода записей */` и выбирать его при создании соответствующих страниц

Comment: Ну, собственно, я так изначально и хотел в топономике сайта сделать - унификацию названий. Теперь же совсем запутался: где оставлять чпу-топономику, а где исправить. Если я у вводной страницы раздела изменю имя шаблона с page-раздел на my-temp-cat-01, то как сайт будет подхватывать именно его, а не просто page.php?

Comment: В итоге сработало с get_posts. Рабочий вариант выложил ответом

Answer (score 0):

После разных попыток решения задачи вывода анонса материалов на вводной странице сработала связка с get_poists вида:

```html
 <?php global $post; $args = array( 'numberposts' => 9 , 'category' => 24, 'orderby' => 'date');
    $myposts = get_posts( $args );
    foreach( $myposts as $post ){ setup_postdata($post); ?>

<div class="flex-cat">
<div class="entry">

<!-- Анонс (вывод контента до more) -->
<?php the_content(); ?>

<div class="date clear"><?php the_time('d.m.Y'); ?></div>

<div class="tag">
<div>Раздел: <?php the_category(', '); ?></div>
<div>Тэги: <?php the_tags('',', ',''); ?></div>
</div>

</div>

<div class="clear"></div>

<div class="pic-thumb"><?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?></div>
<!-- <div class="clear"></div> -->
</div>
<?php } wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Код вставлен в шаблон страницы со слагом: page-категория.php.
В итоге вышло то, что изначально хотел: вводная страница для определенной категории материалов с предварияющими "бла-бла", а ниже цикл вывода самих материалов для этой категории по ID.
Спасибо за участие и поддержку всем откликнувшемся. Буду постигать дальше